# Local Django Server Runs from Windows Command Prompt but not Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, django

I can start my local Django server from Windows cmd prompt and Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) from the same directory using python manage.py runserver.

The website works fine when I start the server from the command prompt, but my connection quickly resets when I start the server from WSL. Why might this be?

Comment: Did you install your Django server into the WSL?